# Batch Script to convert Multiple Excel files to CSV files

Tags: batch-file

I am using vbs to convert multiple excel files in a folder to csv files. It is working fine. Here is the script that i am using in the Batch file.

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR *.xlsx /b/s') DO ExcelToCSV.vbs "%%i" "%%i.csv"
```

It is working fine except that the target file name is having `.xlsx` before the extension. I tried using `%%~ni` for the target and I am getting read error. Is there a way that i can rename a file `a.xlsx` to `a.csv`. currently it is getting converted to `a.xlsx.csv`. The converted file itself is not corrupted. It is just that I do not like that name having `.xlsx`.

Comment: It should work with `ExcelToCSV.vbs "%%i" "%%~ni.csv"` If it fails you could try `%%~dpni.csv` for the full path

Comment: ... I would go with the latter, _(the recursive `dir` command will output full paths)_

Comment: Wow. %%~dpni.csv worked guys. .I have been breaking my head for the last few hours. Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate.